# Influence of variance change in variable $x_2$ on the variance of its OLS estimator

Tags: statistics, regression, variance, regression-analysis

So $Var(\hat{β}_1)=σ^2/\sum_{i=1}^n (x_{2i}−\bar{x})^2$. What would happen if the variance of $x_2$ is increased? The $σ^2$ of the error remains the same but the sum must change, but how?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are talking about the sample variance of $X$. The sample variance is calculated by 
$$
S ^ 2 = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i - \bar{x}_n) ^2,
$$
as such, as the variance of $X$ grows $\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i - \bar{x}_n) ^2$ gets larger, hence the estimated variance of $\hat{\beta}_1$ gets smaller.

Comment: Thank you! How could you explain this intuitively? As of now I would have guessed it was the other way around but why is there a negative relationship between Var X and Var β?

Comment: Well, check out  what "PCA"  is. In a nutshell - if $X$ has large variance, then in the direction of $X$ is potentially very informative. Note that says nothing about whether $X$ helps you to "explain" $Y$, however if it does (you reject $H_0$), then you can be pretty sure ( = Statistically significant)  about the founded relationship.